# Tablix: blank cells when adding new child column groups

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I have a dataset with the following fields:

- SampleHour
- Value
- MeasureType
- Line
- Header
- AggregationON

I've created a tablix with a row group on `SampleHour` and I'd like to have two adjacent column groups, each having the same grouping hierarchy as follows (from parent to child):

```
AggregationON > Line > Header > MeasureType
```

Well when I define the first column grouping structure all works fine: I add a parent column group on `AggregationON`, then a child group on `Line` pointing to the `AggregationON` group and so on.

Then I try to create the second column grouping structure and I proceed like this: I point to `AggregationON` in the first column group and choose "*Add Group->Adjacent Right*" and specify `AggregationON` as the "*Group By*" parameter. The newly created column group header `AggregationON` appears just on the same row as the previous `AggregationON` header as expected.

Then I point to the newly created `AggregationON` and choose "*Add Group->Child Group*" and set `Line` in the "*Group By*" parameter: this time the `Line` group header cause tablix to add a new row. On the left of the newly created header appears a blank new row that is impossible to delete.

If I go on creating child groups to build the whole column group structure, each new column child group will add a blank row on the left. That leads to an unacceptable table header with a mix of texts and blank cells like in the attached screenshot. Any suggestion?

(Creating two column groups with the same structure is due to the need to filter out results differently in the two groupings)

Comment: Thanks akluth for improving readability of my post! I tried also to attach a JPG showing the problem, but I could not manage to, because I am a newby in this forum.

Answer (score 0):

When you create the second column group use the "Column Groups" section on the bottom pane. Click the arrow on the first parent group and select `Add Group -> Adjacent After`.

Then add the child groups normally and you'll end up with something like this:

[image]

Now all you have to do is move the Child1 and Child2 to the rows below, and delete the 2 new rows choosing the option `Delete rows only` and you will have the two groups side by side.

---

Other way to tackle this problem is to have only one group (since in your case the grouping rules are the same) just create a parent group that groups based on the filters you want to apply:

```
Group on: =IIf(<filter expression>, "Group1", "Group2")
```

This is potentially harder because if you have different rules for each group, you have to put them on every single textbox under this new parent group. But at least it should get the result you want.

Comment: Hallo Joao, thanks for your answer. As to my experience, what you are suggesting does not work: you actually drag just the TextBoxes Child1 and Child2 to the new position, but the icons representing the two groups stays there. As soon as you try to delete the corresponding rows, you will be asked if you want to delete only the rows or the group definitions too. Either one of the answers will take you to unpredictable report behaviours.

Comment: I only tested with some dummy data and I didn't have unpredictable behaviours but I can understand that it might happen. I'll add a second alternative to my answer.

Answer (score -2):

I had a similar issue. What worked for me was to use "Merge Cells"

```
Group1....................Group2......................Group3

Group1a.....................................................

.........................Group2a............................

.....................................................Group3a
```

In example above Group1a merges with blank cells below, Group2a merges with blank above and below, and Group3a merges with blank cells above. Then just resize the row.